# ubuntu django and apache, cannot find the site

Tags: django, apache, ubuntu

I am brand new to web app development and thought I would try django as I am familiar with python. I followed the following guide: http://www.lennu.net/2012/05/14/django-deployement-installation-to-ubuntu-12-dot-04-server/ to deploy a django page to the letter. However, I now realize that this guide was for the server version of the OD and i'm running the desktop version. When I try to open my site in chrome (amitash.r) it fails with a page not found. Now when I open localhost, I get an internal server 500 error. All my config files are exactly as stated in the guide. Any fixes?

Comment: Look in the apache error log, /var/log/apache/error.log, and it will most likely tell you what's up

Answer (score 0):

Can you post your mod_wsgi script and Apache VirtualHost file?

Following the instructions from the link you gave, the mod_wsgi script should be in:

```
/srv/my_project/app/conf/apache/django.wsgi
```

The VirtualHost file location from the link should be:

```
/etc/apache2/sites-available/DOMAIN
```

Make sure you enabled your site. If you named your file DOMAIN, like the instructions, you should enable the site using:

```
a2ensite DOMAIN
```